# how do you find the expectation of a continuous random variable conditional on an interval the variable falls in?

Tags: conditional-expectation

$E[\theta|\theta\leq w]$

Will this be simply considered as the $E[\theta\leq w]$?

If yes, how will that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the definition of conditional expectation

$$E[\theta|\theta\leq w]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\theta f(\theta \mid \theta \le w)d\theta$$
where the conditional density is

$$ f(\theta \mid \theta \le w) =\begin{cases} 0, & \mbox{if } \theta > w\ \\ \dfrac{f(\theta)}{P(\theta \le w)}, & \mbox{if } \theta \le w \end{cases} $$
Hence the expected value becomes

$$E[\theta|\theta\leq w]=\dfrac{1}{P(\theta \le w)}\int_{-\infty}^{w}\theta f(\theta )d\theta$$

Comment: You should be able to answer this without referring to a density, because no density for $\theta$ was assumed.  Such an answer would, I think, clarify the concepts, too.

Comment: hi @whuber thanks for the comment. what do you mean answer without referring to the density? using the stieltjes integral and the CDF only?

Comment: That's right.  To keep it simple I think you don't really need to refer to the Stieltjes integral: the key part is normalizing the conditional distribution by $1/F_\theta(w)$.